# Lambda function not working properly in a CSV, returning float error

Tags: python, pandas, csv, lambda

Here is a screenshot of the CSV in question. It is 2nd row - all values in the column need changing.

[CSV Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlnAw.png)

What it's meant to look like:

[CSV with column amend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJVDj.png)

Using the lambda code:

```
ordersClient = ordersClient['*Customer Code'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('0','GIF',1)[:6])
```

It should remove the initial '0', replace with 'GIF' and remove any characters after the last number.
I suspect this needs editting, but I've no idea what to change.

This is the error I'm getting.

```
>>> ordersUnleashed = ordersUnleashed['*Customer Code'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('0','GIF',1)[:6])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4433, in apply
    return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 1088, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 1143, in apply_standard
    mapped = lib.map_infer(
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2870, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Thanks for any help.

---

Full code below:

```
import pandas as pd

ordersClient = pd.read_csv("clientOrders.csv", header=None)
ordersClientColumns = ordersClient.iloc[:,[1, 3, 12, 11, 15]]

#create new dataframe - ordersUnleashed
ordersUnleashed = pd.DataFrame()
ordersUnleashed = ordersClientColumns.copy()
ordersUnleashed.columns = ["*Order Number", "*Customer Code", "*Line Number", "*Product Code", "*Order Quantity"]
ordersUnleashed.to_csv("unleashedOrders.csv", index=False)

ordersUnleashed.insert(2,'Tax Code','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(3,'Tax Rate','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(4,'Exchange','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(5,'Customer Reference','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(6,'Comment','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(7,'Order Date (DD/MM/YYYY)','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(8,'Quote Expiry Date (DD/MM/YYYY)','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(9,'Required Date (DD/MM/YYYY)','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(10,'Warehouse Code','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(11,'Delivery Contact','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(12,'Delivery Name','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(13,'Delivery Street Address','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(14,'Delivery Street Address 2','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(15,'Delivery Suburb','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(16,'Delivery City','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(17,'Delivery Region','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(18,'Delivery Post Code','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(19,'Delivery Country','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(20,'Delivery Instruction','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(21,'Discount (%)','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(22,'Sales Order Group','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(23,'Sales Person Email','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(27,'Line Discount (%)','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(28,'Unit Price','')
ordersUnleashed.insert(29,'Line Comments','')




#ordersUnleashed = ordersUnleashed['*Customer Code'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('0','HAL',1)[:6])
ordersUnleashed.to_csv("toUnleashed.csv", index=False)


Update: Here are the data types

''''
print (ordersUnleashed.dtypes)
*Order Number                     float64
*Customer Code                     object
Tax Code                           object
Tax Rate                           object
Exchange                           object
Customer Reference                 object
Comment                            object
Order Date (DD/MM/YYYY)            object
Quote Expiry Date (DD/MM/YYYY)     object
Required Date (DD/MM/YYYY)         object
Warehouse Code                     object
Delivery Contact                   object
Delivery Name                      object
Delivery Street Address            object
Delivery Street Address 2          object
Delivery Suburb                    object
Delivery City                      object
Delivery Region                    object
Delivery Post Code                 object
Delivery Country                   object
Delivery Instruction               object
Discount (%)                       object
Sales Order Group                  object
Sales Person Email                 object
*Line Number                      float64
*Product Code                      object
*Order Quantity                   float64
Line Discount (%)                  object
Unit Price                         object
Line Comments                      object
''''

After check of data types (*Customer Code is actually an object), I get the following error with lambda:

''''
 ordersUnleashed = ordersUnleashed['*Customer Code'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('0','GIF',1)[:6])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4433, in apply
    return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 1088, in apply
    return self.apply_standard()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 1143, in apply_standard
    mapped = lib.map_infer(
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2870, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
''''
```

Comment: if the issue is with `x` you could try converting it to a string first: 
Change 
`x.replace()` to `str(x).replace()`

Comment: You `'*Customer Code'` column contains floats, not strings. There is nothing wrong with the lambda function itself.

Comment: the issue is with the column - the lambda function was working a couple days ago but i had to change the sheet a little.

it's meant to take the '0', replace it with 'GIF' then any characters after the last number to be removed.

so 0825YORK becomes GIF825 - and this occurs through the column

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how it's a float if the content is '0825YORK'.

Comment: Sorry if this is a bit obvious but, have you checked `ordersClient.dtypes` and printed the head, just to check the csv was correctly loaded into the dataframe?

Comment: Also, if you can reproduce the problem using only the head, it could help if you add the output of `ordersClient.head().to_dict()` to your question, so we can work on it.

Comment: Obvious is fine - I've just added the full code.
For reference, the lambda code actually worked previously, now I don't know why.

Comment: why is it that you are writing to csv twice?

Comment: taking data columns from one csv to another csv with correct column format. at the moment it seems easier just to write to a new one. after it's all resolved i'll refine it.

@alec_djinn i've added the extra code to show the dtypes of the columns, and *Customer Code is actually an object, not a float. so i'm not sure what the lambda replace problem is?